# Compatibility of Apache Cassandra with YugaByte

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

Do the drivers and cqlsh that come with Apache Cassandra work with YugaByte?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes because the YugaByte Cloud QL ([YCQL](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/)) API is wire compatible with Apache Cassandra QL. This means that YugaByte DB servers implement the same wire protocol and modeling/query language as Apache Cassandra QL. Since client drivers, command line shells, IDE integrations and other ecosystem integrations rely on this wire protocol and modeling/query language, they are expected to work with YugaByte DB as is without any further modifications.

More details here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/faq/compatibility/